# Identify every submatrix satisfying condition

Tags: r, matrix, submatrix

In the following matrix I'm trying to identify every largest rectangles formed by 1's as shown in the picture. 
Rectangles can have just one row only if they have more than **3** columns. 
Rectangles can have just one column only if they have more than **3** rows. 
Rectangles should have less than **maxcol** columns and **maxrow** rows and more than **mincol** and **minrow**. In the picture mincol=minrow=2. maxrow=maxcolumn=6

Tried to use the subset function but it provides 1's submatrixs not every superimposed rectangles.

```
mdat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0), nrow = 4, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE) 

dimnames(mdat) <- list(  c("row1", "row2", "row3","row4"), c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4","col5","col6"))
```

[image: Identified rectangles]